# this.setState is not clear out array on first attempt of onClick event and have to do it twice to clear out array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dropzone

Working on a document upload section of a component. User can drop their file to upload and below the drop area is a submit, cancel button, and the list of files they are going to submit. The cancel button should clear the `files` array.

However, the first time you click, it still prints out the file name due to the file still being there. Click it again and it erases the file. Not sure why this happens.

The function in question is the `handleClick(event)`.

Interestingly, it does clear the list of files being rendered on the page, but the array still shows as populated view the `console.log` in the `handleClick(event)`.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { submitDocument } from '../../actions/documents';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class SubmitDocuments extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            files: []
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({
            files: []
        })
        console.log(this.state.files);

    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.state.files);
        // filesToBeSent.pus
    }

    onDrop(files) {
        // console.log(files);
        // files.push(this.state.files);
        this.setState({
            files
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className='panel panel-default'>
                    <div className='panel-heading'>
                        <h4><strong>Submit Documents</strong></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div className='panel-body'>
                        <Dropzone className='dropzone' onDrop={this.onDrop}> 
                            <h3>Click to add files or drag files here to upload</h3>
                        </Dropzone>
                        <div>
                            {_.map(this.state.files, f =>
                                <h5 key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</h5>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                        <button type='button' className='btn btn-danger' onClick={this.handleClick}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        ); 
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        documents: state.home.documents
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { submitDocument })(SubmitDocuments);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` can run asynchronously.

Try changing your handler to:

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
        files: []
    }, () => console.log(this.state.files));
}
```

Your console statement should now print what you expect on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the state in `handleClick(event)` method as below.

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state, files: []
    })
}
```

Comment: `console.log` is still showing the file as being there with the first click.